# notation for postive values only of a variable?

Tags: notation

Is there a to express certain values of a variable?

For instance, suppose $s \in \mathbb{Z}$, but there is an instance in which you are interested only in $s > 0$. I suppose you could write $s^+$, but I was wondering if there is a convention to follow.

**EDIT**. Sorry for the confusion. I have the following in mind. Consider a regression

$$y = \alpha + \beta s + \varepsilon$$

where $s \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now suppose we want to regress just on the values $s > 0$. I express this in writing, but I wanted to also distinguish this in the formula, like:

$$y = \alpha + \beta s^+ + \varepsilon$$

so the reader is reminded.

Comment: why doesn't s>0 work? (I don't know why that renders as an o its a zero)

Comment: $s > 0$? $s\in \mathbb{Z}_+$? $s \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$? $s \in \mathbb{N}$? "Consider only the values of $s$ which are positive"?  Without additional context about what it is that you are trying to accomplish, it is a little hard to provide a reasonable answer.  Can you please edit your question to give some additional context about why you need this notation and how you intend to use it?

Comment: That being said, I would think that $s^+$ is poor notation.  This notation implies that you have been handed a value $s$, then you have done something to it.  If I understand the question correctly (and the question is, to my mind, somewhat unclear), then what you are actually trying to do is specify the universe in which your $s$-values can live, i.e. they must be positive.  Hence it makes sense to alter the notation for the set containing the values of $s$, rather than altering the notation for the values themselves.